# How to get a autoindent in a winform TextBox (or RichTextBox) C#?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm trying to build a very simple text/code editor using a TextBox, and I want to keep the indent from the last line typed. So I need a way to carry over the indent from the last line to this line. I've looked at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20217407/auto-indent-when-a-new-line-is-made), but that doesn't seem to cut it. I've tried this:

```
class SpaceBox : TextBox
{
    public static int spaces = 4;

    protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
    {
        if (keyData == Keys.Tab)
        {
            this.SelectionLength = 0;
            this.SelectedText = new string(' ', spaces);
            return true;
        }
        return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
    }

    protected override void OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        //base.OnKeyDown(e);
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
        {
            this.Text += "\n";
            this.Text += new string(' ', spaces);
            this.SelectionStart = this.Text.Length;
            return;
        }

        base.OnKeyDown(e);
    }
}
```

But that, for some reason, types four spaces then types the enter. Am I on the right track with the example above?

Thanks for the answers.

Comment: Welcome to SO. SO is not a coding service. Please re-frame your question and show what is your research and what have you tried so far? and have a look at [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: You may have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20217407/auto-indent-when-a-new-line-is-made

Comment: What is the question? How to carry over a variable number of spaces instead of the fixed 4? Well you will need to count the spaces at the start of the last line.. There are many helpful functions to get at the line numbers, character positions etc in a richttextbox..

Comment: @TaW I want to have the TextBox autoindent. So if where are two tabs (8 spaces), are on he last line, I want two tabs on this line. Like in visual studio when you hit enter, it keeps the same indent from the last line.

Answer (score 0):

Got it. I just need to add a if statement to the ProcessCmdKey() method like this:

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
    {

        if (keyData == Keys.Tab)
        {
            this.SelectionLength = 0;
            this.SelectedText = new string(' ', spaces);
            return true;
        }

        if (keyData == Keys.Enter)
        {
            this.AppendText(new string('\n', 1));
            this.AppendText(new string(' ', spaces));

            return true;
        }
        return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
    }
```

Comment: How does that work without calculating the right value for `spaces`?